# How to ssh a remote device from a already logged in device using robot framework?

Tags: windows-7, robotframework

I have the following Test topology:

```
Windows Computer ----- Router1 ----- Router2
```

I need to do SSH from "Windows Computer" to "Router2". Its not possible through direct SSH, since its in different network (Access denied).

So, I need to SSH "Router1", then again from "Router1" I need to connect Router2 through SSH.

Can anybody tell me, how to do this in ROBOT FRAMEWORK.

Till now I am able to SSH from "Windows Computer" to "Router1" using the following "Keywords":

```
*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
    Open Connection         ${HOST}
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?
This would require sshpass on router1. There is a more involved way using an [SSH key](https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password) to avoid using the password. This is all assuming you don't need to run Robotframework on it, and are happy to run terminal commands on it.

```
***Keywords***
    Remote Bash  
    [Arguments]  ${command}  
    [Documentation]  Runs a given terminal command on remote server and returns terminal output.  

    ${test} =    SSHLibrary.Execute Command    ${command}
    Return From Keyword   ${test}
***Test Cases***
RemoteSSH
    Open Connection         ${ROUTER1_IP}
    Login   ${ROUTER1_USER}     ${ROUTER1_PW}
    Remote Bash  sshpass -p ${ROUTER2_PW} ${ROUTER2_USER}@${ROUTER2_IP}
    Remote Bash  echo 'Hello World!'
```